# How to send info from one postback handler to another?

Tags: asp.net, controls, webforms

I have a third-party CustomControl which requires some info for databinding or anything else what it happen in a postback event handler. 
Trying to send this info via, say, dropDownList i face that this dropdownlist postback event handler isn't firing before CustomControlEventHandler, as it happens in ASP.Net. What is usual workaround?

Or I should never rely on server side transfer and try to transfer this info on client-side etc.?

Comment: This is the same basic problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081642/how-do-you-manage-the-order-of-firing-events-in-asp-net, right?

Comment: @Jonathan I agree, both questions are pretty similar.

Comment: yes, but i considered useful to formulate it more appropriate way, because i still don't know the right decision, and stackoverflow doesn't have an exact answer. i do not appeal to solve my programming problem - it is already solved someway, but i found a lack of technology understanding and maybe someone will give a right explanation.

Comment: What keeps you from manually call some method that manipulates the grid from your dropdownlist's event handler?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**note**: AutoPostBack="true"